# REST API design authenticated user: /products or /<userid>/products

Tags: rest, api

I'm building a web app with VueJS as front end and authenticating user to an API with JWT.

If I want a API to display only user products (filtered), should the route be:

/api/products

and the backend do the filter
or

/api/userid/products

and restrict access to others users products

Answer (score 1):

You'll have the user_id from the JWT so for us we just use `/api/products` in our software. We avoid having multiple sources of data as that can create confusion and anything in the JWT is authenticated so we can trust that.

If I wanted to allow a user to see products from other users, I'd use `/api/products/search?user_id=XXX` for a flexible search system that could be expanded to search products by other criteria.

Answer (score -1):

I find it better to make the user id part of the uri. Ultimately this is subjective, but it has a few advantages:

1. It makes really clear that the list of product in this case is a subordinate of users. There's no doubt it's the 'entire list' if it looks like a sub-resource.
2. It keeps the door open in the future to allow users to access product lists of other users.
3. I like the idea of giving every entity in my API a completely unique URI. To me, every user in your example has a personal product list and each product list is a unique resource.